# How to never show keyboard in Xamarin Android?

Tags: android, xamarin

I'm working with Xamarin(Android). I have a WebView and KeyboardView with my custom keyboard that is always showing. The problem is when I touch any text box in a website, standart keyboard pops-up. How do I completely disable android keyboard from showing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your webview is defined in your code as web_view. So

```
web_view.Focusable = false;
web_view.FocusableInTouchMode = false;
```

That will solve your problem you wont get the keyboard when you click to textbox in a website.